# using different table to authenticate user in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have created separate table called subscribers in mysql changed config/auth.php settings to 'model' => App\Subscribers::class, 'table' => 'subscribers'. 
I have login form on home page, that submits to the home page.
so in routes i have below

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::post('/', 'LoginController@validate');
```

my LoginController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function validate()
    {
        // attempt to do the login
        $auth = Auth::attempt(
            [
                'email'  => strtolower(Input::get('email')),
                'password'  => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
            ]
        );
        if ($auth) {
            return Redirect::to('dashboard');
        }

    }
}
```

when i login i get below error

Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::validate() should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array $customAttributes = Array)

Comment: Rename your function to something else then 'validate'. I think that's why you are having this issue. Don't forget to change your route to.

Comment: okay let me try, also in my if Auth::attempt() IDE is telling me that function is not defined. would you know what do i need to put for 'use' at the top?

Comment: why are you not using the builtin authentication from laravel? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication. Or do you want to do something special regarding authentication?

Comment: i was building it while learning laravel at the same time, and i had already built subscriber model and db table with lot of info, so i wanted to just auth with that table instead.

Comment: its not showing error after changing the function but just gives me blank page when i hit login

Comment: `use` is irrelevant to your IDE's complaint about a non-existing method. It's a facade, one of many in Laravel and don't worry about such warnings as long as your code works (you'd get a fatal error otherwise). If you want support for facades in your IDE, check if it has some Laravel plugin for them. And, to solve your issue with login, just rename your `validate()` method in login controller to something else, and continue working from there.

Comment: If you get a blank page it means that you auth failed. Cause in your if statement you only check if auth was succesull. But if it fails you don't have a return back to the login screen.

Comment: yes the auth did failed i put else and returned pass, i was getting different hash.  did you want to put your solution as answer so i can up vote. and also thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use 'validate' as a name for a function. It will conflict with:

`App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate`

Also add an 'else' to your if statement so if your authentication fails you can redirect the user back to the login screen for example.